# dynamic active class menu using php

Tags: php

I have 20 modules page and this code for add active class for each page to side menu :

```
$x = 0;
$showoptions = '';
if (checkaccess("cats")) {
    if ($_GET['mod'] == "cats") {
        $active = 'class="active"';
    }
    else {
        $active = '';
    }

    $showoptions.= '<li ' . $active . '><a href="?mod=cats"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i><span> categories</span></a></li>';
    $active = '';
    $x++;
}

if (checkaccess("uploads")) {
    if ($_GET['mod'] == "uploads") {
        $active = 'class="active"';
    }
    else {
        $active = '';
    }

    $showoptions.= '<li ' . $active . '><a href="?mod=uploads"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i><span> Uploads</span></a></li>';
    $active = '';
    $x++;
}
```

for print output :

```
#if the user can't access any of the sub option menus hide the main option menu
    if($x > 0){
    echo $showoptions;
    }
```

I have two questions:

- My Code is readable? and True? (if not what's better way)
- `if` condition better Or `switch/case` Or `if/elseif` methods?

My URL IS : `http://mydomain . com/admin/?mod=[name]`

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know, what is your `checkaccess` do, do not know what do you mean true.
I am coding like this, it's more readable for me:

```
if (checkaccess("cats")) {
    $active = '';
    if ($_GET['mod'] == "cats") {
        $active = ' class="active"';
    }
    $showoptions.= '<li' . $active . '><a href="?mod=cats"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i><span> categories</span></a></li>';
    $x++;
} elseif (checkaccess("uploads")) {
    $active = '';
    if ($_GET['mod'] == "uploads") {
        $active = ' class="active"';
    }
    $showoptions.= '<li' . $active . '><a href="?mod=uploads"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i><span> Uploads</span></a></li>';
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: `checkaccess` is a function for check user access to this page and show menu link. your mean is `if`/`elseif` for 20 page is better?!

Comment: if / elseif and switch are the same. It's ok for any nymber of pages, but your code will be unreadable later. I suggest you to create a router, what is load a class, and call the proper method of it. But first, you should check how to progamming in OOP, what is a later lesson for you i think, but give a shot.